# TASM: How to print an array of ints? x86

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, tasm

Given an array of words (DW):

```
array DW 12 34 56 79
```

there seems to be no documentation as to how to print such array. I know I must use interrupt 21, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: Do you know how to print just one single number?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez No, not really. I am relatively new to this field.

Comment: [`int 21h`](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21.html) has no service to print word integer value. There are services to output single character or string. If you want as final output on screen something like "12, 34, ...", you will have to convert integer values into string first, then you can use `int 21h,ah=9` service to output that string(s). .. *"no documentation"* = check https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info  this particular problem mentioned there too, plus much more. (especially "FAQs" part)

Comment: To print an integer, you must print out each digit individually. This means converting each digit to ASCII (hint: '0' + n). It's assembly; you have to do a lot more yourself.

Comment: @MikeHarris Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!